# Web Api can't upload multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using the solution by *Filip W* from [here](https://github.com/filipw/WebApi.Html5.Upload). For a single file, it works just fine. But for multiple files I get the error: `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error`.

```
Response
Cache-Control no-cache
Content-Length 0
Date Tue, 08 Apr 2014 15:23:07 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma no-cache
Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcYW5kcmV5LnNoZWRrb1xkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEzXFByb2plY3RzXFBSRVBQXFBSRVBQXGFwaVx1cGxvYWQ=?=
Request
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Cookie __AntiXsrfToken=b7dbaa70f0cd4c35a8a3a22d75faae03
Host localhost:4955
Referer http://localhost:4955/test.html
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
```

Simple html:

```
<body>
    <form action="/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="somefile">File</label>
        <input name="somefile" type="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: 500 status is a server error, have you actually tried debugging the web api methods you are calling to make sure you are not getting an exception?

Comment: I found two:Exception:Thrown: "Maximum request length exceeded." (System.Web.HttpException)
A System.Web.HttpException was thrown: "Maximum request length exceeded."
Time: 08.04.2014 22:56:49
Thread:Worker Thread[8672]

Comment: Second:Exception:Thrown: "Error reading MIME multipart body part." (System.IO.IOException)
A System.IO.IOException was thrown: "Error reading MIME multipart body part."
Time: 08.04.2014 22:56:49
Thread:Worker Thread[8672]

Comment: Damn, it was about request lenght. Thanks everyone and excuse me for being such inattentive.

Comment: I will mark as answer IsabelHM post as her answer was first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The accepted answer, while correct is not the solution to this problem. In case anyone finds this while googling, I thought I'd steer you in the right direction.

Here's how  to solve the problem ...
Edit web.config and add a maxRequestLength to the system.web section like so:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="2000000"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This'll increase your upper limit which is really the cause of the OP's issues

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, but actually I found this reason already by myself and just mark @IsabelHM answer because here weren't other options.

Comment: @andrey.shedko This answer should be marked as correct, the accept answer is wrong, In future if you solve your own problem either remove the question, or more appropriately add the answer yourself and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

If you are following [this tutorial](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/) by Filip W, I think the action name has typo

Change

```
<form action="/api/upload"
```

To

```
<form action="/api/uploading"
```

Comment: My controller name is UploadController. So i change this name. It's not big deal anyway.

Comment: 500 is server error, so perhaps post your RouteConfig since you had modified the tutorial code.